# Opening a specific Julia notebook (via IJulia) in the REPL

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

the Julia (i'm using 0.6.2) REPL makes it possible to do some work and then execute

```
julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook(dir=pwd(), detached=true)
```

which nicely launches jupyter in the directory specified by dir.

is it possible from the REPL to include a specific notebook to open ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me recently (julia v 1.5.1, macOS 10.14):

```
using IJulia
notebook(dir="/path/to/directory/with/my/notebook",detached=true)
```

One thing I noticed is starting jupyter in the background, julia doesn't give you a link to where to open the notebook in the browser.

I was able to open `http://localhost:8888/` in my browser to find the notebook, although I thought there was a URL token needed. This link in the browser also worked:

```
file:///$HOME/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-12912-open.html
```

I got this from the REPL documentation:

```
?notebook

#search: notebook

#  notebook(; dir=homedir(), detached=false)
# ..etc
```

Answer (score 1):

this kinda works (but feels like a hack):

```
julia> ;jupyter notebook someJuliaNotebook.ipynb 2>/dev/null &
```

which produces a relatively clutter free terminal window i can keep using.